# jQuery .getJSON method fails with parseerror

Tags: jquery, .net, getjson, ashx, parse-error

Although this seems to be a common error, none of the other similar questions on SO have revealed the solution to me. So let me share my code.

Client side HTML/jQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            function DisplayJSON() {
                $.getJSON("Test1.ashx")
                    .done(function (p) {
                        alert(p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName);
                    })
                    .fail(function (x, textStatus, error) {
                        alert("Get JSON failed, status: " + textStatus + ", error: " + error);
                    });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" name="btnTest" value="Get JSON" onclick="DisplayJSON();" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Server side HTTP handler .NET/C# (Test1.ashx):

```
    public class Test1 : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        Person p = new Person()
        {
            FirstName = "Angela",
            LastName = "Smith",
            Gender = "F",
            BirthYear = 2009
        };

        // to serialize an object to string
        string jsonText = fastJSON.JSON.ToJSON(p);

        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.Write(jsonText);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int BirthYear { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

When I attempt to retrieve the JSON content, it always fails with the status of "parseerror" and an error of "SyntaxError: Invalid character". I've looked and looked and I'm just not finding the culprit. If I put a breakpoint in my server side code, it never gets hit so it would appear that the getJSON call is not formed properly, but I'm just not seeing anything wrong with it. Hopefully someone else can point out what I'm doing wrong.

**UPDATE:** error image

[image: error image]

Comment: so, just check string what you get from server

Comment: can you provide screenshot with parse error?

Comment: Apparently the call is never even getting to the server as my breakpoint on the first line of server code is not reached.

Comment: i mean error in browser, _SyntaxError: Invalid character_ this from in console i think?

Comment: Have you tried this code to see if it works for you?

Comment: ofcource not, i don't know what is _fastJSON.JSON.ToJSON_ and what it return

Comment: if used this line instead: `string jsonText = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(p);` all work fine

Comment: fastJSON is simply an alternative JSON library: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159450/fastJSON. But, I'll try the native library when I get a chance.

Comment: I guess I wasn't thinking this through on my last comment, but whatever code/library is being used for the serialization part is irrelevant in my case. As I stated earlier, the failure is occurring before the server-side code can even be invoked. But as you requested, I made a screen shot of some details I was able to capture in the Chrome debugger. Not sure how helpful it will be, but here it is: http://www.libersys.net/public/json_parseerror.png

Comment: this interesting, as i see you go to _error_ handle, but i though you just get exception.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95012/discussion-between-grundy-and-ponggod).

Comment: Hmm, I just tried this code on my office workstation and it worked right away. The only things I changed were 1) separating these code snippets out of a bigger project into one of its own, and 2) referencing the jQuery source from a CDN. I'll need to figure out what is the real culprit so I can avoid it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I finally figured out what was wrong and of course it turned out to be something silly that I overlooked. The project in which I was doing this proof-of-concept test at home is one that is configured for forms authentication. When I was trying to test that page, I skipped the login step so apparently the request to the ASHX was being rejected due to lack of an authenticated user. If I first log in before navigating there, it works fine. When I tried this at the office, I just threw it into a brand new project which wasn't configured for forms authentication.